# appending an li to ul with user input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having a lot of trouble with this for some reason even with examples, what am I doing wrong here?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="item">       

<div id="itembutton"> <button onclick="appendList()">Add</button></div>

<ul id ="listitems"></ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function appendList() {
    var ul = document.getElementById('listitems');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var item = document.getElementById('item');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gmyag/777/)**.

I must be tired or something, I'm following the tutorials as closely as possible.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What results are you expecting? I am seeing things being appended to the list in the JSFiddle. (See [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhiqicurxdy9572/Screenshot%202015-03-01%2020.41.45.png?dl=0).)

Comment: your code is working normally.

Comment: Just based on a quick look, item is the `name` of the `<input>` element.  Not the `id`.  So, the third line of your Javascript looks suspect.  Also, `document.createTextNode()` takes a string.  Not sure what you're expecting that line to do.

Comment: @ctt i expected the line to pass var item as a string into create textnode, is that not what's occuring?  var item being the user input.

Comment: @Mars01, you probably want to use `item.value`.  `item` is the actually DOM node for the input field.

Comment: @ctt ah yes, that's what I've been doing im not sure why that was missing in the example.  I'm still getting nothing even with item.value passed into create textnode.  I've updated my link to illustrate.

Comment: @Mars01 as I stated above, `item` is the `name` attribute of the `<input>` element.  Since it's not the `id`, `document.getElementById("item")` will not return the `<input>` element.  In this case, it'll return nothing.

Comment: @ctt thank you, simple reading comprehension error on my part. all is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an `ID` to your `input` field. Because you called the `value` by `ID` Name, but there is no `id` in your input field.

Below the code is:

```
<input type="text" name="item" id="item">
```

Demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/3ac73ffj/)

Comment: yeah i figured this out, cheers for the straightforward and correct answer, though.